# Creating pronunciation dictionary for ASR

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, nlp, speech-to-text

I am working on ASR(automatic speech recoginition) on Somali data as master thesis and now I am stuck with how to create a phonetics or pronunciation dictionary for it. I searched over net and could not find one.

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Can someone guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

I had posted a similar question in reddit as well and I got a response from [Nikolay Shmyrev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432021/nikolay-shmyrev) :

"If you want to convert latin script, you can write simple rules yourself. Something like [this](https://github.com/dmort27/epitran/blob/master/epitran/data/map/som-Latn.csv).  Or you can use epitran as is. "

Thanks to [Nikolay Shmyrev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432021/nikolay-shmyrev) who originally answered in reddit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of existing [ASR datasets](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/best-speech-recognition-datasets-for-machine-learning/) on the web, though I couldn't find one specifically for Somali. If you do happen to find one, and it doesn't cover the words interested in, you can extend it with the [g2p tool](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq).

If you want to make a pronunciation dictionary from scratch, phonetic dictionaries are usually bootstrapped with handwritten rules. You can find a list of phonemes for your language in the Wikipedia page about your language and write a simple Python script to map words to phonemes.

Comment: Thanks. For the time being I have done the similar thing by mapping individual alphabets of a word to its phoeneme. I don't know how good it is.